# How to roll back changes in NX monorepo

Tags: monorepo, nx-monorepo

In my NX monorepo I have two apps: Next.js and Srapi. I tried to update Next.js' version manually by:

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. update root `package.json` with desired Next.js version number
3. `npm install`

Now whenever I try to start any of the applications by running
`npx nx serve web`
which previously worked just fine, I get the following error:

```
> NX The current directory isn't part of an NX workspace.
```

I've checked git log since maybe config files were broken, but no changes in any of NX-related files like `nx.json` or `project.json` in any app. I've ran
`git reset --hard`
to get rid of any changes, but to no use. Now I've checked out to `main` (where no changes were made) and even there it gives me the same error.

How can I rollback to working state?